# Rotate metro style

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, rotation, .net-4.5

I am playing with a Metro Style Application at the moment (.NET 4.5 RC [C#\XAML], VS2012 RC) and I have one problem which I am unable to solve.

I would like to achieve that my app will change the layout when hosting device is rotated (+-45). I have prepared two layouts in XAML - one for landscape and second one for portrait, and I have done some animation for Visual States:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ControlContentLandscape" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ControlContentPortrait" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Snapped"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

But I do not know what to do next. How to set my app that it will perform these animations when my device is turned into portrait mode?

Comment: Have you had a look at the default templates? You can see how they have done there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have analysed the Grid App template. And I have noticed that the main page there inherits from the *LayoutAwarePage* class which is present in the Common folder. The *LayoutAwarePage* class provide the handler for *WindowSizeChanged* event which is using the *VisualStateManager* to switch between states - this was the missing part in my current project. The solution is:

1. Manually handle the *WindowsSizeChanged* event and use the *VisualStateManager* class and *GoToState()* method
2. Create new project (Grid App) and fit into it the current project.